# Export data from Elastic search to S3 using Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I wish to transfer data from ultrawarm Elastic search to s3 in the source region using AWS Glue ETL. I am having difficulty trying to find a documentation on it. Can someone help with me with it.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom connection type `custom.spark` and then set the configuration option to OpenSearch that starts with the prefix `es`. Read more about it and see the example [in the documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#marketplace-spark-connect-options).

*Alternatives*

1. If you have the choice it is always better to directly push from the application to S3 instead of getting the data from OpenSearch to S3.
2. For a full dump use the [elasticsearch-dump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump) command to copy the data from your OpenSearch cluster to your AWS S3 bucket.
   For the input use your OpenSearch SERVICE_URI.
   For the output, choose the Amazon S3 path including the file name that you want for your document.